# How should I pass this std::array<> to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, stl

```
std::array<LINE,10> currentPaths=PossibleStrtPaths();
LINE s=shortestLine(currentPaths);                       //ERROR
```

---

```
LINE CShortestPathFinderView::shortestLine(std::array<LINE,10> *currentPaths)
{
std::array<LINE,10>::iterator iter;

LINE s=*(currentPaths+1);                      //ERROR

for(iter=currentPaths->begin()+1;iter<=currentPaths->end();iter++)
{
     if(s.cost>iter->cost)
     s=*iter;
}

std::remove(currentPaths->begin(),currentPaths->end(),s);

    //now s contains the shortest partial path  
return s; 


}
```

At both those statements I'm getting the same error:  `no suitable conversion from  std::array<LINE,10U>*currentPaths to LINE` . Why is this so? Should I pass the array another way? I've also tried passing *currentPaths*  as a reference, but it tells me that a reference of the type cannot be initialized.

Comment: `*(currentPaths+1);` can you do that? or did you mean `(*currentPaths)[1]`

Comment: @ahenderson I want assign the second LINE object of _currentPaths_ to _s_. Isn't `*(currentPaths+1)` the same as `currentPaths[1]`?

Comment: Unless `null` is a possible value passing by reference is the better way to go. With your method you might be accessing `(*currentPaths)[10]` which is the same as `currentPaths[1]`. remember you have a pointer to an array not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you tried a reference and it failed.  I don't know why, because that was the correct thing to do.

```
LINE CShortestPathFinderView::shortestLine(std::array<LINE,10> &currentPaths);
```

From the sounds of it, you also used a reference for the temporary variable.  That's wrong.

```
std::array<LINE,10>& currentPaths = PossibleStrtPaths(); // WRONG
std::array<LINE,10>  currentPaths = PossibleStrtPaths(); // RIGHT
LINE s = shortestLine(currentPaths);
```

And finally, the first element is number zero.  The subscripting operator `[]` is preferred when you are doing array access.  So:

```
LINE s = currentPaths[0];
```

But you also can easily get the first item from the iterator.

Final code:

```
/* precondition: currentPaths is not empty */
LINE CShortestPathFinderView::shortestLine(std::array<LINE,10>& currentPaths)
{
    std::array<LINE,10>::iterator iter = currentPaths.begin();
    LINE s = *(iter++);

    for(; iter != currentPaths->end(); ++iter) {
       if(s.cost>iter->cost)
          s=*iter;
    }

    std::remove(currentPaths.begin(), currentPaths.end(), s);

    //now s contains the shortest partial path  
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I've inserted the code you've given me, but I'm still getting an error message at the line `LINE s=shortestLine(currentPaths); `: `error C2664: 'CShortestPathFinderView::shortestLine' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size>' to 'std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size> &'`

Comment: @Ghost: Show the *entire* error message, including what `_Ty` and `_Size` are.  I wonder if you have more than one type named `LINE`.

Comment: [
    1>              _Ty=CShortestPathFinderView::Brains::LINE,
    1>              _Size=10
    1>          ]
1>          and
    1>          [
    1>              _Ty=LINE,
    1>              _Size=10
    1>
   ]

   Brains() is the function I'm calling _shortestLine_ from.

Comment: @Ghost: You have two different types named LINE.  An array of `Brains::LINE` isn't the same as an array of `::LINE`.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt  Ohh, I didn't see that. Thanks a lot! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing `(currentPaths+1)` which is of type `std::array*` (more precisely: you are incrementing the pointer and then accessing its pointed data) while you probably want to retrieve the first element of `currentPaths`, that is: `currentPaths[0]` (the first index in an array is 0).